# How to make corners of progress bar round in css

Tags: html, css, web, progress-bar

For my progress bar I would like to have the edges rounded and the percentage on display inside the progress bar. I managed to get the corners of the progress value to be round but not the bar/background. Also the animation doesn't seem to work.

~css

```
.progress-bar body { 
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", arial, sans-serif;
padding: 2em;
margin: 50px auto 0;
max-width: 800px;
border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
}


.progress-bar .skill h3 { 
font-size: 1em; 
color: #fff;
left: 1em;
line-height: 1;
position: absolute;
top:1em;

}

progress { border-radius:15px; -moz-border-radius: 15px;}

.progress-bar progress, progress[role] {
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
 background-size: auto;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 15px;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 }



  .progress-bar .skill-list {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 1em;

   }

   .progress-bar .skill {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;

    }

    .progress-bar .skill ::-webkit-progress-value { 
    -webkit-animation: bar-fill 2s;
    width: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
     }



     .progress-bar .skill-1::-webkit-progress-value {
     background: #ff9e2c;
     border-radius: 15px;
     -moz-border-radius: 15px;
     }

 .progress-bar .skill-1::-moz-progress-bar {
    background: #ff9e2c;
   border-radius: 15px;
   -moz-border-radius: 15px;
   }

  .progress-bar .skill-2::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #4ecdc4;
  border-radius: 15px;
   -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  }

 .progress-bar .skill-2::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: #4ecdc4;
  border-radius: 15px;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 }

 .progress-bar .skill-3::-webkit-progress-value {
 background: #ff6b6b;
 border-radius: 15px;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 }

.progress-bar .skill-3::-moz-progress-bar {
 background: #ff6b6b;
 border-radius: 15px;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 }




 @-webkit-keyframes bar-fill {
  0% { width: 0; }
 }
 @keyframes bar-fill {
 0% { width: 0; }
 }
```

~html

```
<div class="progress-bar">
<body>
<ul class="skill-list">
  <li class="skill">
    <h3>HTML/CSS</h3>
    <progress class="skill-1" max="100" value="80">
      <h2>80%</h2>
    </progress>
  </li>
  <li class="skill">
    <h3>Javascript</h3>
    <progress class="skill-2" max="100" value="45">
     <h2>45%</h2>
    </progress>
  </li>
  <li class="skill">
    <h3>PHP</h3>
    <progress class="skill-3" max="100" value="35">
      <h2>35%</h2>
    </progress>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you could use bootstrap for progress bars.

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:80%">
      HTML/CSS
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:45%">
      JavaScript
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:35%">
      PHP
  </div>
</div>
```

Take a look at this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/67ueLwgq/

Answer (score 3):

A clean solution without JavaScript. Only HTML5 and CSS3. Tested in Webkit:

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/t5aw06nm/)

```css
progress {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 padding:15px 0 0 0;
 margin:0;
 background:none;
 border: 0;
 border-radius:50px;
 text-align: left;
 position:relative;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
 height:40px;
 width:80%;
 margin:0 auto;
 background-color:#dadada;
 border-radius:100px;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;
 height:40px;
 margin:0px -10px 0 0;
    padding-left:50px; /* Rounded corners requires a padding */
 background:#ff9e2c;
 border-radius:100px;
}
progress.skill-1::-webkit-progress-value {
    background:#ff9e2c;
}
progress.skill-2::-webkit-progress-value {
    background:#4ecdc4;
}
progress.skill-3::-webkit-progress-value {
    background:#ff6b6b;
}
progress:after {
 margin:-25px 0 0 -32px;
 padding:0;
 display:inline-block; /* Here is the magic to move with the progress */
 float:left;
 content: attr(value) '%';
    color:#555;
```

```html
Progress width increases from 12% because the rounded corners:
<progress max="100" value="0" class="skill-1"></progress>
<progress max="100" value="15" class="skill-2"></progress>
<progress max="100" value="35" class="skill-3"></progress>
<progress max="100" value="90" class="skill-1"></progress>
<progress max="100" value="100" class="skill-2"></progress>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Typescript code:**

```ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class ProgressBarComponent {
    @Input() percentage: number = 0;

    ...
}
```

**Component CSS:**

```css
.bar-background {
  position: relative;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.bar-background .fill-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: red;
}
```

**Component HTML:**

```html
<div class="bar-background">
  <div [ngStyle]="{ transform: 'translateX(calc(-100% + ' + percentage + '%))' }" class="fill-bar">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wuzwyh?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Comment: Thank you, I know this is an old post, but this is a newer answer and its perfect, exactly what I needed! I tested it on plain html/css and changed the 'inherit' values with pixels (width, height, border-radius etc.)